# Excel: conditional formatting values in a column based on other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I've 3 columns in a spreadsheet and I want to highlight the values in column `value` based on the bounds specified in columns `min` and `max`.

[image]

If the number in column `value` lies within the range [min, max], the cell has to be highlighted green. If the number is less than  `min` or greater than `max` the cell has to be highlighted red. And if there is no value in `value`, the cell has to be colored yellow.

Example,

[image]

Suggestions on how to define the rules for conditional formatting in excel will be really helpful.

Comment: =and(a2>=b2,a1<=c2) assuming your data starts in A1 that should help you to the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with 3 conditional formatting rules based on formulas. Highlight your values and then create those rules based on these formulas:

First Formula (fill is yellow)

```
=isblank(a2)
```

Second Formula (fill is green)

```
=and(a2>=b2,a2<=c2)
```

Third Formula (fill is red)

```
=OR(A2<B2,A2>C2)
```

Then go into [Conditional Formatting... Manage Rules] and order them as such:

[image]

It's imporant to have the yellow one first, and then select the "Stop if True" box. You don't need this for the others.

Final Output:

[image]